# No Update after DataRow-Selected is clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to convert this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

to a Data depending row element (there are more than just one, but to make it simple, I altered the code a little bit).

However, after I click/ tap in the debugger a row, the select box isn't updated... Before I extract it to this, everything was ok and behave like expected. And I don't see any cruel failure in my code, which could cause this behaviour.

```
DataRow generateRows(int index, List<bool> selected) {
    String id = globals.localData.keys.elementAt(index);
    var data = globals.localData[id];
    return (DataRow(
      selected: selected[index],
      onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          selected[index] = value!;
        });
      },
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(data['dat'])),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the Problem by myself,
the var "selected" has to be declared in the class-body, not in the widget-body.